# What is exactly the "legal right to work in this location"?

Tags: support, jobs

I mostly ask this because I'm from Spain and I wouldn't mind working on the United States.

I have the legal right to work there ... provided a did get a Green Pass for which usually helps a lot having a job offer in the first place so... Does it refer just to something like I'm of age and I'm not crazy nor do I intent to kill the USA president?

Or should I uncheck the "legal right" checkbox? And if I do, would that mean that I won't be appearing on US employers searches?

Comment: If you check that box, and you don't have the legal right, then expect some blow back. It would be disingenuous of someone to say the have the right when they don't--a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its whether you could legally turn up that country today and work there. For Example as you are an EU citizen you have the legal right to come to the UK and work there all you want. However you do not have the Legal Right to work in the US, unless you can get an employer to sponsor you for a Visa etc.

So my guess would be that you can put whatever location you want to work in, but if you don't have the right to work there, you would not tick this box, then if an employer say in the US see's your CV, he will see that you want to work there, but you don't have a Visa, so if they want you, they are going to have to sponsor your Visa application, which may or may not put them off, depending how amazing you are.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. "This is a key search field, and it defaults to required for employers. So if it's not filled correctly, you won't show up!" ... so an employer would need to actually seek for people in my situation.

Comment: That sounds right.

Comment: But they don't know his citizenship, so the work required to get him a work permit may be easy or it may be very hard.

Comment: True, I don't know how common this is in the US, but this question is on every job application you get here in the UK. Employers don't want to go through the hassle of getting work permits, even if its relatively straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

I added "today" to the end of the phrase since that seemed to be the source of most of the confusion:

> I have the legal right to work in this location

vs

> I have the legal right to work in this location today

Comment: I guess it depends on the meaning of the word today? If you mean the today it is being checked then that's one thing, but if you mean the today it is being read that is something else entirely. ;)

Comment: maybe "right now" then?

Comment: Maybe a footnote/tooltip/link to a FAQ item would be in order for this option. Not everything has to be self-explanatory in one line. If the user isn't sure whether it applies to him, he can click through to a longer explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's referring to if you can work there right now. So if you have the necessary authorization to start working there right now, then you can check it.

Comment: I don't have it because I don't have a proper offer. Having a proper offer would actually make it easier to get a green pass but I won't be receiving any offer at all (not through careers anyway) if I don't mark the checkbox... So ... infinite loop.

Comment: I'm stating that you can work there right now, like book a flight now and start working later today.

Answer (score -2):

The guidance that the system shows seems vague to me. I'm uncertain if I should say yes or no. I have not got any visa to US yet but I am applying for job; and if that's the incorrect thing to do, it's not obvious to me.

It should be clearer - some would only apply for visas if they knew they would have opportunities.

Comment: If you do not have a visa and work permit, you do not have the legal right to work in the location mentioned. This applies not just to the US, but any other location. They can't legally employ you unless you have the proper permits, so if you don't have them, say no. Some jobs specifically state that they offer assistance with this sort of thing, and you can always ask in advance if a company would be willing to assist you if they found you to be qualified.

Comment: You can apply for a job without having a visa, but you should not check the box that says you have a "legal right" to work in the US, because you don't, yet. If your application for the job is accepted, it means your new employer has accepted the additional burden of sponsoring you for a visa, so you'll have the legal right to work for them when your visa is granted. But it hasn't been, yet, so don't tick the box. Does that clear it up? The box is for the employer's benefit, not yours.